# argparse error: 'nargs must be %r to supply const' % OPTIONAL)

Tags: python, argparse

I keep getting the error: `raise ValueError('nargs must be %r to supply const' % OPTIONAL)` when I use the following code in python:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--username', type=str, required=True,
                    help="Username to login. Required")
parser.add_argument('--password', type=str, required=True,
                    help="Password to login. Required.")

parser.add_argument('--chromedriver', type=str, const=r'C:\histdata\batfiles\chromedriver.exe')
parser.add_argument('--output', type=str, const='C:\\histdata\\batfiles\\')
```

It fails on the line for `--chromedriver`. When I move the next line before it to test that too. It fails. That is `--output` line gives the same error.  I realize that people in the past have posted a similar error message, but I still don't see how to fix it.

Comment: You're trying to add optional parameters (i.e. no `required=True`) and those need you to set a value for `nargs`? If you don't provide `nargs`, argparse tries to derived it from `action`, but you don't provide that either. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: 'Nargs must be optional to supply const".  Are you looking for `default=` ?

Comment: More specifically, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to use `default` instead of `const`? The former is used to store the default value of an argument, the latter is for specifying const value, that will be stored, when the argument is provided.